# Subscribe to custom Twitter RSS feed?

Tags: twitter, rss, events

Does there exist a service that will allow me to create a twitter search (i.e. "find all tweets with the tag '#aardvark' that are emitted by someone whose name contains the string 'pete'") and then "subscribe" to this query (for instance through RSS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter Advanced Search has some of what you're looking for -- f'r instance, here's [the feed for tweets with the tag '#aardvark' that are emitted by someone named 'pete'](http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=+%23aardvark+from%3Apete) (which has no results, sadly)

Unfortunately, there are no wildcards that I'm aware of, so it's an exact-match on the tag and name.

There are a lot of other options available, though.

---

Perhaps it might be possible to [magic-up some google-fu](http://www.booleanblackbelt.com/2009/09/google-search-the-asterisk-wildcard-and-punctuation/) to do this -- and then set up a [google-alert for the RSS feed](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/how_to_use_the_new_google_web_feeds.php).

Again, I could not find a way to limit it to a specific sender, nor to hashtags (since the "#" is ignored)